# Calculate Average Qty On Hand of Inventory

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find the average qty on hand of my inventory over a date range from parameter `@StartDate` by averaging the ending qty from each day.  I have three tables: a part table, a part transaction table, and a warehouse table, mocked up below.

```
PartNum      |   PartNum     TranDate     TranQty      |   PartNum   OnHandQty
----------   |   ------------------------------------  |  --------------------
P1           |   P1          6/28/2016    5            |   P1        30
P2           |   P1          6/26/2016    3            |   P2        2
             |   P1          6/26/2016    -1           |
             |   P1          6/15/2016    2            |
             |   P2          6/15/2016    1            |
```

If today is 6/30/2016 and `@StartDate` = 6/1/2016, I expect a result like:

```
PartNum    AverageOnHand
------------------------
P1         22.9
P2         1.5
```

However, I don't know what function would best allow me to get to an appropriate weighted sum which I could divide by the difference in dates.  Is there a SumProduct function or similar that I can use here?  My code, so far, is below:

```
select 
    [Part].[PartNum] as [Part_PartNum],
    (max(PartWhse.OnHandQty)*datediff(day,max(PartTran.TranDate),Constants.Today)) as [Calculated_WeightedSum],
    (WeightedSum/DATEDIFF(day, @StartDate, Constants.Today)) as [Calculated_AverageOnHand]
from Erp.Part as Part
right outer join Erp.PartTran as PartTran on 
    Part.PartNum = PartTran.PartNum

inner join Erp.PartWhse as PartWhse on 
    Part.PartNum = PartWhse.PartNum

group by [Part].[PartNum]
```

Comment: which rdbms (sql-server, oracle, mysql, postgresql)?

Comment: also using your example tables can you show me how you arrived at the 22.1 (I am curious about your formula not syntax). So warehouse table is always current quantity? and transaction table when positive it adds to that quantity or subtracts from it?  In other words is a positive integer a sale or a return?

Comment: @Matt sql-server.  You've got it right, the warehouse table returns the current quantity.  The transaction table is positive when it adds.  So, at end of day on 6/27/2016 there were 25 P1 on hand.  I got 22.1 by calculating the qty available at the end of each day, taking a sum, and dividing by the count.  This results in an average by day (as opposed to by month, hour, or continuously).

Comment: I think it's not possible with just a query, because you need to calculate the amounts backwards until you reach the start date, while doing so you can build the sums and count the days in PL/SQL.

Comment: Just noticed an error in my calculation--the average should have been 22.9, not 22.1 (I was looking at beginning of day instead of end of day).  I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I think I figured out a method close to your train of thought but using a running total mechanism hopefully one of the ways i gave you will work, let me know thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with a sum.  First, I multiplied the final quantity on hand by the number of days in the range.  Next, I multiplied each change in inventory by the time from `@StartDate` until the `TransDate`.

```
select 
    [Part].[PartNum] as [Part_PartNum],
    (max(PartWhse.OnHandQty)*datediff(day,@StartDate,Constants.Today)-
         sum(PartTran.TranQty*datediff(day,@StartDate,PartTran.TranDate))) as [Calculated_WeightedSum],
    (WeightedSum/DATEDIFF(day, @StartDate, Constants.Today)) as [Calculated_AverageOnHand]
from Erp.Part as Part
right outer join Erp.PartTran as PartTran on 
    Part.PartNum = PartTran.PartNum

inner join Erp.PartWhse as PartWhse on 
    Part.PartNum = PartWhse.PartNum

group by [Part].[PartNum]
```

Thanks for your help everyone!  You really helped me think it through.

Comment: Where does the `WeightedSum` come from? Is that supposed to be the same as the expression before it? I couldn't get your query to match up with mine.

Comment: If I read your query correctly you would be doing ((OnHand * TotalDaysDiff) + (TransactionQuantity * DaysDiffFromStart)) / TotalDaysDiff?  That is definitely not an average of DailyOnHand quantity.  for your example take your P1 that would be ((30 * 29 days) + ((2*14)+(-1*25)+(3*25)+(5*27)))/29 which would give you 37.34483 ............................................

Comment: @shawnt00 my idea was to solve for the numerator of the average first, and then divide by the denominator. I found that to be helpful while troubleshooting.

Comment: @Matt you're right--I got the sign wrong when I copy/pasted into the forum--the real database counts some transactions as positive and others as negative, so in some cases I had to flip the sign.  I changed the + to a - so that it's consistent with the data I presented at the top.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the transactions to compute daily quantities. Add in the missing dates and look backward to the most recent date to fill in the daily quantities. I think I'm going to try for a better solution than this one.

http://rextester.com/JLD19862

```
with trn as (
    select PartNum, TranDate, TranQty from PartTran
    union all
    select PartNum, cast('20160601' as date), 0 from PartWhse
    union all
    select PartNum, cast('20160630' as date), 0 from PartWhse
), qty as (
    select
        t.PartNum, t.TranDate,
        -- assumes that end date corresponds with OnHandQty
        min(w.OnHandQty) + sum(t.TranQty)
            - sum(sum(t.TranQty))
                over (partition by t.PartNum order by t.TranDate desc) as DailyOnHand,
        coalesce(
            lead(t.TranDate) over (partition by t.PartNum order by t.TranDate),
            dateadd(day, 1, t.TranDate)
        ) as NextTranDate
        -- if lead() isn't available...
        -- coalesce(
        --    (
        --        select min(t2.TranDate) from trn as t2
        --        where t2.PartNum = t.PartNum and t2.TranDate > t.TranDate
        --    ),
        --    dateadd(day, 1, t.TranDate)
        -- ) as NextTranDate
    from PartWhse as w inner join trn as t on t.PartNum = w.PartNum
    where t.TranDate between '20160601' and '20160630'
    group by t.PartNum, t.TranDate
)
select
    PartNum,
    sum(datediff(day, TranDate, NextTranDate) * DailyOnHand) * 1.00
        / sum(datediff(day, TranDate, NextTranDate)) as DailyAvg
from qty
group by PartNum;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sql-server 2012 + method that is interesting.

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       p.PartNum
       ,CAST(t.TranDate AS DATE) AS TranDate
       ,i.OnHandQty
       --,SUM(SUM(t.TranQty)) OVER (PARTITION BY p.PartNum ORDER BY CAST(t.TranDate AS DATE) DESC) AS InventoryChange
       ,i.OnHandQty - SUM(SUM(t.TranQty)) OVER (PARTITION BY p.PartNum ORDER BY CAST(t.TranDate AS DATE) DESC) AS InventoryOnDate
       ,DATEDIFF(day,
          CAST(ISNULL(LAG(MAX(TranDate)) OVER (PARTITION BY p.PartNum ORDER BY CAST(t.TranDate AS DATE) ASC),@StartDate) AS DATE)
          ,CAST(t.TranDate AS DATE)
       ) AS DaysAtInventory
    FROM
       #Parts p
       LEFT JOIN #Transact t
       ON p.PartNum = t.PartNum
       LEFT JOIN #Inventory i
       ON p.PartNum = i.PartNum
    GROUP BY
       p.PartNum
       ,CAST(t.TranDate AS DATE)
       ,i.OnHandQty
)

SELECT
    PartNum
    ,(SUM(ISNULL(DaysAtInventory,0) * ISNULL(InventoryOnDate,0))
    + ((DATEDIFF(day,MAX(TranDate),CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) + 1) * ISNULL(MAX(OnHandQty),0)))
    /((DATEDIFF(day,CAST(@StartDate AS DATE),CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) + 1) * 1.00) AS AvgDailyInventory
FROM
    cte
GROUP BY
    PartNum
```

This one actually gave me the 22.9 but 1.53333 the 333 gets introduced because 1 day has to get put somewhere so I stuck it as the current inventory.

Here is a previous method I answered with and this one it is a little easier to conceptualize the data..... I would be curious about performance differences between the 2 methods.

Some of these steps can be combined to be a little more concise but this works (although I got 22.6 not .1 or .9....)  I rounded everything to a whole date while doing this so that you don't have to worry about beginning and end of day.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '6/1/2016'

;WITH cteDates AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS d
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
       d + 1 AS d
    FROM
       cteDates c
    WHERE c.d + 1 <= CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
    --get dates to today beginning of day
)

, ctePartsDaysCross AS (
    SELECT
       d.d
       ,p.PartNum
       ,ISNULL(i.OnHandQty,0) AS OnHandQty
    FROM
       cteDates d
       CROSS JOIN #Parts p
       LEFT JOIN #Inventory i
       ON p.PartNum = i.PartNum
)

, cteTransactsQuantityByDate AS (
    SELECT
       CAST(t.TranDate AS DATE) as d
       ,t.PartNum
       ,TranQty = SUM(t.TranQty)
    FROM
       #Transact t
    GROUP BY
       CAST(t.TranDate AS DATE)
       ,t.PartNum
)

,cteDailyInventory AS (
    SELECT
       c.d
       ,c.PartNum
       ,c.OnHandQty - SUM(ISNULL(t.TranQty,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY c.PartNum ORDER BY c.d DESC) AS DailyOnHand
    FROM
       ctePartsDaysCross c
       LEFT JOIN cteTransactsQuantityByDate t
       ON c.d = t.d
       AND c.PartNum = t.PartNum
)

SELECT
    PartNum
    ,AVG(CAST(DailyOnHand AS DECIMAL(6,3)))
FROM
    cteDailyInventory
GROUP BY
    PartNum
```

Here is the test data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Parts') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #Parts
    END

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Transact') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #Transact
    END

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Inventory') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #Inventory
    END

CREATE TABLE #Parts (
    PartNum CHAR(2)
)

CREATE TABLE #Transact (
    AutoId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    ,PartNum CHAR(2)
    ,TranDate DATETIME
    ,TranQty INT
)

CREATE TABLE #Inventory (
    PartNum CHAR(2)
    ,OnHandQty INT
)

INSERT INTO #Parts (PartNum) VALUES ('P1'),('P2'),('P3')

INSERT INTO #Transact (PartNum, TranDate, TranQty)
VALUES ('P1','6/28/2016',5),('P1','6/26/2016',3),('P1','6/26/2016',-1)
,('P1','6/15/2016',2) ,('P2','6/15/2016',1)

INSERT INTO #Inventory (PartNum, OnHandQty) VALUES ('P1',30),('P2',2)
```

I am thinking 1 recursive cte might be simpler might post that as an update.